# UISplitViewController setting viewControllers a second time crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I am using a `UISplitViewController` on `ARC`.

I setup the controller in my `AppDelegate`, then make it the `rootViewController`.  I have made sure to make it a `property`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

Setting the root and detail using the `viewControllers` property works fine when first creating.  And it works fine again when setting a second time, but I get a crash on the third time I try setting the `viewControllers` property.

Here is how I set those:

```
    Screens *edit = [[Screens alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController *c = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:edit];

    if ([Utility isIpad]) {
        Map *a = (Map *)[[MyAppDelegate instance].splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a, c, nil];
        UISplitViewController *splitView = [MyAppDelegate instance].splitViewController;
        splitView.viewControllers = viewControllers;// <--- Crashes here
    } else {
        [self presentModalViewController:c animated:YES];
    }//end
```

Why would it crash when I try to set the `viewControllers` property?  It almost seems like it is released, but I know that the `splitViewController` is still there...

Could this be something to do with ARC?

**Stacktrace:**

[image]

Comment: What's the backtrace when it crashes? Also, doubt it's ARC related.

Comment: Ok, dumb question. How do I see the backtrace? I only what is in the Debug Navigator.

Comment: Yeh in the debug navigator there should be a backtrace. There's a slider at the bottom which if you slide all the way to the right you will get the complete backtrace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same error just now. In my case the problem was that I had originally set up the detail view controller to be a delegate of the `UISplitViewController`. Then I refactored to make the root view controller handle things, but I forgot to remove the connection from the `.xib` file.

So, when I set `splitView.viewControllers` the first time everything worked, but then my original detail controller would get released and the `UISplitViewController` was left with a bad pointer as `delegate`. The next time I set the `viewControllers` property, the `UISplitViewController` tried to call its delegate through the pointer and crashed.

You write that you set up the controller in your app delegate, so this may not be exactly the same problem you had. Still, double check to make sure the `delegate` property of the `UISplitViewController` is set correctly!

Comment: +1. My app's been crashing because of this and I've just spent the last three hours trying to figure this out. You saved me who knows how much grief!

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I could give something back – Stack Overflow has saved me weeks of debugging pain :).